# Error en datatable en laravel

Tags: laravel, datatables

Buenas estoy usando datatable en laravel, este pertenece al paquete `yajra`, primera vez que uso esto y pues me sale un error:

```
message: "SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'created_at'. (SQL: select * from [Empleados] order by [created_at] desc)"
exception: "Illuminate\Database\QueryException"
```

Yo tengo creado una tabla Empleados en donde tiene nombres y fechacreacion pero no tiene `created_at`, entonces...se puede cambiar esa columna que viene por defecto del datatable? por mi columna FechaCreacion?

Codigo:

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $menu = Menu::all();
        $submenu = SubMenu::all();
        $hoy = new \DateTime();

        if($request->ajax())
        {
            $data = Empleado::latest()->get();
            return Datatables::of($data)
                    ->addIndexColumn()
                    ->addColumn('action', function($row){

                           $btn = '<a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->IdEmpleado.'" data-original-title="Edit" class="edit btn btn-primary btn-sm editProduct">Editar</a>';

                           $btn = $btn.' <a href="javascript:;" data-toggle="tooltip"  data-id="'.$row->IdEmpleado.'" data-original-title="Delete" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm deleteProduct">Eliminar</a>';

                            return $btn;
                    })
                    ->rawColumns(['action'])
                    ->make(true);
        }

        return view('Empleados/index', compact('menu', 'submenu', 'hoy'));
    }
```

Comment: Sin el código, noo sabemos cómo lo estás implementando. Puedes probar como dice en la documentación https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/master/manual-order

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya agregue el codigo

Comment: Aunque viendo tu consulta, tendrías que pasarle un agumento a latest `$data = Empleado::latest('FechaCreacion')->get();` pues el error puede estar ahí

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ ya me salio al agregar latest('FechaCreacion') ya que con el ordercolumn no salia. Muchas gracias

Comment: ok, agregué una respuesta para que quede para otros que tengan el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [`latest/oldest`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

El método `latest` te permite ordenar fácilmente los resultados por fecha. Por defecto, el resultado será ordenado por la columna `created_at`.

Pero si la columna `created_at` no existe en tu tabla te generará una excepción. Entonces deberás pasar como argumento el nombre de la columna por la que deseas ordenar.

```
$data = Empleado::latest('FechaCreacion')->get();
```